# Disable UITextField editing but still accept touch - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I'm creating a `UITextField` that has a `UIDatePicker` as input. I don't want the textfield to be edited (copy, paste, cut and select text), but I only want to show `UIDatePicker` when users touch the `UITextField` and the chosen date will be displayed on `UITextField`.

I've tried to disable editing by using `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`, but the TextField doesn't give me response when I touch it.

What should I do to achieve it in Swift 3?

Comment: implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()` in TextField's delegate, there you can call the UIDatePicker and return false

Comment: Assuming you have other textfields in the same view, then you could use the Tag property to identify which TextField has been selected, and return true for all of the others

Comment: Would replacing the `UITextField` with a `UIButton` solve your case? User taps your button, you show the date picker, then once user decides on date, you hide the date picker. You can style a `UIButton` to look like a `UITextField`.

Answer (score 7):

To prevent the copy/paste menu appearing…

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if dateTextField.isFirstResponder {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            (sender as? UIMenuController)?.setMenuVisible(false, animated: false)
        })
        return false
    }

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

And implement…

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // show UIDatePicker
    return false
}
```

This hides the menu before it has a chance to appear

Comment: Worked great for me. I didn't need the textFieldShouldBeingEditing part in Swift 3.

Answer (score 3):

Use  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { retrun bool } in place of textFieldShouldBeginEditing.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        textField.tag = 1
        textField.inputView = datePicker
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.tag == 1 {
            textField.text = ""
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField.tag == 1 {
            textField.text = ""
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Create a New class with Name StopPasteAction.swift

import UIKit

```
class StopPasteAction: UITextField {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Add the class new class with you Curren textfield

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I can still do a long press in the `UITextField` and trigger the paste dialog.

Comment: @toddg Please check the code on dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/84wb7k23wdlkazc/UItextDelagte.zip?dl=0
If work please let me know

Comment: I don't need it that badly. PS I'm not the one that down voted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can `addTarget` to `textField`, and in the textField delegate method, disable the editing like below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tedtField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tedtField.delegate = self
        tedtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(respondsToTf), for: .touchDown)
    }

    func respondsToTf()  {

        // 
        print("you can pop-up the data picker here")
    }

    // MARK: - textfield delegate
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: could work, but have to show & hide datePicker by yourself

Answer (score 1):

swift 3:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var myTextField           : UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      self.myTextField.delegate     = self
   }

   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      if textField == myTextField {
         // code which you want to execute when the user touch myTextField
      }
      return false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solve this problem

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var testTxf: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    testTxf.delegate = self
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(testFunc))
    testTxf.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    testTxf.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func testFunc() {
    print("tap")
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can create a subclass of a UITextField and implement the methods below:

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

        if action == #selector(copy) || action == #selector(cut) || action == #selector(paste){
            return false
        }
        else {
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        }
    }
}
```